# can we see intermediate output in oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

In Oozie, if there are 2 jobs in a workflow. first is mapreduce and second is Pig Script.
can we see the output of mapreduce job.
if yes then where ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the intermediate data in 2 ways.

1) By creating oozie shell action calling a shell script which moves the temporarily created intermmediate files to a different location.

Here is a shell script to move all images in a file to a differnt folder. refer this script.

```
## For all the images in a folder run through a loop
```

for file in ~/Desktop/My_pictures/*jpg
   do

```
## basename will remove the path (~/Desktop/My_pictures) and also
## remove the extension you give as a second argument
```

name="$(basename "$file" .jpg)"

```
## create the directory, the -p means it will create 
## the parent directories if needed and it won't complain
## if the directory exists.
```

mkdir -p ~/Desktop/My_pictures/"$name"

```
## copy the file to the new directory
```

mv "$file" "~/Desktop/My_pictures/$name"
done

## #

2) removing the pig action and only running the map reduce program ( Java action).

The first one suits your requirement.